# Can't do knockback

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm playing Minecraft bedwars and I try every time to throw someone off the maps but i can't do any knockback.

Can someone please help me? I searched for help but couldn't find anything to help me.

It's like I weigh only 1 gram in Minecraft but the other people weigh like 200000000000 tons or something.

Doing combos is impossible without doing knockback.

I would really like to ask Hypixel to because my friend was banned for kill aura but her wifi was horrible and she was floating so the staff saw it and banned her for a month they really need to look a little bit better before they ban people.

Comment: 1) this is 2 questions, make it 1 2) servers can have custom game mechanics (including custom knockback) 3) please use words 4) you shouldn't suggest things for hypixel to do here, those should go on the hypixel forum 5) i find it hard to believe someone would be banned for kill aura because of bad internet, especially with how hypixel handles most bans very well 6) THIS IS NOT THE HYPIXEL FORUMS

Comment: This isn't the place for this question, but also having a staff false ban for ka is really weird. When I used to be really laggy I almost got anti-cheat banned for movement hacks, but lagging looking like ka is really weird, they possibly might be lying to you

Comment: You can try to w-tap and strafe. On hypixel I can do knockback with 250 to 300 ping

Answer (score 1):

People typically don't take knockback when they are laggy. This is probably what your issue is.

Another possibility is that your opponent has anti-knockback hacks (which aren't too rare) but considering it seems like you have this issue with a lot of people I'd guess not.

Answer (score 0):

They are either w tapping to sprint forward reducing their kb, or moving side to side making their movement different which reduces kb, or block hitting which is blocking your hits, and hitting you back.